# Square of an approximate unit is an approximate unit

Tags: operator-theory, c-star-algebras, approximation-theory

Let $A$ be an abelian $C^*$-algebra with approximate unit $(u_\lambda)$. I'm trying to show that $(u_\lambda^2)$ is an approximate unit as well. In particular, I'm stuck at showing that
$$\lim_\lambda \| a-u_\lambda^2 a \| = 0$$
for all $a \in A$.

Here is my approach:

Since $A$ is spanned by its positive elements, we may suppose that $a\geq 0$. We have
$$\lim_\lambda u_\lambda^2 a = \lim_\lambda u_\lambda^2 \sqrt{a}^2 = \left(\lim_\lambda u_\lambda \sqrt{a}\right)^2 = \sqrt{a}^2 = a$$

and the result then follows. Note that commutativity was used for the rule $(ab)^2 = a^2b^2$ to hold.

Is the above correct? Can we drop the assumption that $A$ is abelian?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: initially thought it was true for general C*-algebras. As pointed out in the comments, I forget about $\lambda_1 \leq \lambda_2 \Rightarrow u_{\lambda_1} \leq u_{\lambda_2}$. To remedy this, assuming abelian fixes it since $0 \leq x \leq y \Rightarrow x^2 \leq y^2$ in the abelian case, but not in general.

Let $A$ be any C*-algebra, abelian or not. Then if $(u_\lambda)$ is an approximate unit, these are all positive contractions, and so their squares are as well. To see that the limits are as desired, notice that
$$ \|a - u_\lambda^2a\| \leq \|a - u_\lambda a\| + \|u_\lambda a - u_\lambda^2 a\| \leq \|a - u_\lambda a\| + \|u_\lambda\|\|a - u_\lambda a\|$$
where the first inequality just follows by adding and subtracting $u_\lambda a$ and using the triangle inequality and the second comes from the submultiplicativity of the norm. From here its clear that the right hand side tends to 0 since $(u_\lambda)$ is an approximate unit (the norm differences tend to zero and $\|u_\lambda\| \leq 1$).

Now assuming that $A$ is abelian, $\lambda_1 \leq \lambda_2 \Rightarrow u_{\lambda_1} \leq u_{\lambda_2} \Rightarrow u_{\lambda_1}^2 \leq u_{\lambda_2}^2$, so that $(u_{\lambda}^2)$ is an approximate identity.

Comment: Thanks. I guess a problem could be that $0 \leq u \leq v \implies u^2 \leq v^2$ can fail in non-abelian $C^*$-algebras.

Comment: Also, how do you deduce $\Vert a- u_\lambda a \Vert \leq \Vert a  - u_\lambda \Vert $ (second inequality first term, where does it come from?)

Comment: You're right, thats a typo - fixed. And although that inequality can fail, the square of a positive element is still positive. Moreover its always true that if $a$ is a positive contraction then so is its square ($a^2 = a^*a$ is positive as $a$ is self-adjoint, and the fact that its contractive just comes from using continuous functional calculus and the fact that $x \in [0,1]$ implies that $x^2 \in [0,1]$).

Comment: Yes, but we need that $\lambda_1 \leq \lambda_2 \implies u_{\lambda_1}^2 \leq u_{\lambda_2}^2$, and I don't see why that holds :/

Comment: Also, what do you think about my proof?

Comment: Right! For some reason that property of approximate units escaped me. You're right then, to have that property we do want abelian for my argument - will edit accordingly. As with your proof, I think its fine if you can prove that you can pull the square out of the limit like that (something I'm not sure of, and I probably doubt in the non-abelian case).

Comment: The square function $ x \mapsto x^2$ is continuous I believe, since multiplication is continuous in a Banach algebra. But I used the property $(ab)^2 = a^2 b^2$, so that part does use the abelian part.

Comment: Thanks for the help!